# CodeIgniter Tank_auth. Undefined property: Auth::$db

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

Fresh installation of `tank_auth` library over Codeigniter 2.1.3.

When I try to access 'http://localhost/es/auth/register' gets following PHP error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Auth::$db
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 201

Everything seems to be configured and 'autoloaded'.

**Edit:** My *'/application/config/autoload.php'* file contains following lines:

```
$autoload['packages'] = array();
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'xmlrpc','encrypt');
$autoload['helper'] =  array('url', 'file');
$autoload['config'] = array();
$autoload['language'] = array();
$autoload['model'] = array();
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: You have to load the db library first. In

autoload.php :
`$autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);`

Comment: Thanks Keval, but it was already loaded...

Comment: Check this may be help you https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/commit/644dd101a11207a042cf03b02885847caf99f0ff

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm using 'tank_auth' and 'mysql'. I don't see the point.

Comment: Again, I'm using 'tank_auth' (https://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/), not 'Ion Auth' (http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/)...

Answer (score 2):

What about changing the array elements order? Just try to put 'session' before 'database', It is probably a stupid change - *because the codeigniter sample is just like the one you have* - but it's the only difference I can see with my environment:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'database');
$autoload['helper'] = array('array', 'url', 'form', 'string', 'date', 'language', 'static', 'cookie');
```

If it does not work you can try to manually load the database in the code, just to see any clue:

```
$this->load->database();
```

Ah, and take a look that your database settings will be ok in config file:

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "myusername";
$config['password'] = "mypassword";
$config['database'] = "mydatabase";
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
```

Keep an eye to your log config too:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;
```

Maybe some problems related to pconnect? try it with FALSE value. Sorry if it does not help a lot, it's the only stuff that came to my mind.